# After a while integrated webcam is disconnected

Tags: 12.04, webcam

When I boot my ubuntu 12.04 i can see the output of my webcam through cheese, skype, etc... but then it freeze and in the dmesg it shows that is disconnected and it disappears from lsusb. Also the /dev/video* disappears.

It was working before, but for some reason now i have this problem. I think it was an update...

Let me know if you need more information.

thanks in advance.

Here are some outputs.

dmesg:

```
~$ dmesg | grep video
[    1.246713] pci 0000:00:02.0: Boot video device
[   31.964037] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   31.964925] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HP Webcam-50 (05c8:0222)
[   31.972137] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo

~$ dmesg | grep Webcam
[   31.964925] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HP Webcam-50 (05c8:0222)
[   31.971458] input: HP Webcam-50 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.0/input/input6
```

dmesg line that appears when the problem occurs:

```
Nov 17 18:46:39 XXXX kernel: [  146.380681] usb 2-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 3
```

line that disappear after the problem in lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05c8:0222 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink)
```

luvcview output:

```
~$ luvcview
luvcview 0.2.6

SDL information:
  Video driver: x11
  A window manager is available
Device information:
  Device path:  /dev/video0
ERROR opening V4L interface: No such file or directory
```

No video0 file.

```
~$ ls -lha /dev/video*
ls: cannot access /dev/video*: No such file or directory
~$ ls /dev/video*
ls: cannot access /dev/video*: No such file or directory
```

ker.log output:

```
~$ more /var/log/kern.log | grep video
Nov 17 08:06:25 bones-lp kernel: [49207.763326] PM: resume of drv:uvcvideo dev:2-1.5:1.0 complete after 446.656 msecs
Nov 17 08:06:25 bones-lp kernel: [49207.763329] PM: resume of drv:uvcvideo dev:2-1.5:1.1 complete after 446.620 msecs
Nov 17 08:06:25 bones-lp kernel: [49208.704020] video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
Nov 17 13:59:19 bones-lp kernel: [65285.984306] PM: resume of drv:uvcvideo dev:2-1.5:1.1 complete after 177.736 msecs
Nov 17 13:59:19 bones-lp kernel: [65285.984334] PM: resume of drv:uvcvideo dev:2-1.5:1.0 complete after 177.808 msecs
Nov 17 13:59:19 bones-lp kernel: [65287.193393] video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
Nov 17 15:49:43 bones-lp kernel: [    1.242691] pci 0000:00:02.0: Boot video device
Nov 17 15:49:43 bones-lp kernel: [   34.506239] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
Nov 17 15:49:43 bones-lp kernel: [   34.506715] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HP Webcam-50 (05c8:0222)
Nov 17 15:49:43 bones-lp kernel: [   34.514181] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
Nov 17 16:57:35 bones-lp kernel: [ 4104.806501] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uvcvideo
Nov 17 16:57:35 bones-lp kernel: [ 4104.907525] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
Nov 17 16:57:35 bones-lp kernel: [ 4104.916846] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
Nov 17 17:00:30 bones-lp kernel: [ 4279.157010] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uvcvideo
Nov 17 17:06:18 bones-lp kernel: [ 4627.158181] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
Nov 17 17:06:39 bones-lp kernel: [ 4647.411770] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
Nov 17 17:26:49 bones-lp kernel: [ 5855.992986] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uvcvideo
Nov 17 17:27:14 bones-lp kernel: [ 5880.845078] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
Nov 17 18:44:48 bones-lp kernel: [    1.246713] pci 0000:00:02.0: Boot video device
Nov 17 18:44:48 bones-lp kernel: [   31.964037] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
Nov 17 18:44:48 bones-lp kernel: [   31.964925] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HP Webcam-50 (05c8:0222)
Nov 17 18:44:48 bones-lp kernel: [   31.972137] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the webcam is actually dead! It just happened to me too for no reason on my Compaq CQ100 notebook, didn't do any updates or anything! Found this thread googling for the same problem..

Whenever i try to initialize the camera the LED next to it briefly lights up then goes out.. No video. Trying again the application (guvcview) tells me there is no camera detected. Looking at the dmesg output i can see that the camera just disconnects as soon as i try to start it.

```
sudo rmmod uvcvideo && sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```

brings `/dev/video0` back but it keeps failing...

```
[   74.525794] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   74.526429] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[   74.724449] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 4
[   74.996089] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[   75.160048] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=10f1, idProduct=1a13
[   75.160063] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[   75.160074] usb 1-4: Product: HP Webcam-50
[   75.160084] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: importek
[   75.162549] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HP Webcam-50 (10f1:1a13)
[   75.200842] input: HP Webcam-50 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/input/input11
[  144.715843] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uvcvideo
[  150.517385] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HP Webcam-50 (10f1:1a13)
[  150.555981] input: HP Webcam-50 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/input/input12
[  150.561353] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[  150.561364] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
```